# How to specify size for X11 device in pixels?

Tags: r, graphics, x11

The documentation for `grDevices::X11` recommends to put something like the following code

```
setHook(packageEvent("grDevices", "onLoad"),
        function(...) grDevices::X11.options(width = WIDTH,
                                             height = HEIGHT,
                                             xpos = XPOS))
```

...in one's `.Rprofile` file in order to set the default geometry for X11 devices' windows.

I have the desired width, height, and xpos in ***pixels***, whereas the code above expects these values to be in inches.  Does R have some way to convert from pixels to inches?

---

FWIW, I did try passing strings like `"1000px"` to `grDevices::X11.options`, but this resulted in errors like

```
Warning message:
‘mode(width)’ differs between new and previous
     ==> NOT changing ‘width’
```

Comment: You may need to query the window manager's 'dpi' setting.

Comment: Are you running this in Windows or Linux?

Comment: @G5W: Generally Unix, though not necessarily Linux.  (OSX is the most common exception.)